# Using a default font for captions

Tags: python, pdf, fonts, imagemagick, wand

I'm trying to use `python3-wand` to recreate the following command-line invocation:

```sh
$ convert -size 4330x -density 300x300 -background transparent -gravity center -fill grey label:"This is a long text" -trim -rotate -54 +repage -resize 1984x2806 -extent 2480x3508 /tmp/watermark.png
```

using the following code:

```py
width_px = 2480
height_px = 3508
hypothenuse = int(math.sqrt(width_px**2 + height_px**2) * 0.8)
with Image(
    width=hypothenuse,
    height=hypothenuse,
    resolution=300,
    pseudo="xc:transparent",
) as img:
    img.gravity = "center"
    img.caption(
        args.watermark,
        font=Font(
            "/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusSans-Regular.otf",
            color=Color("grey"),
        ),
    )
    img.trim()
    img.rotate(-math.degrees(math.atan(height_px / width_px)))
    img.transform(resize=f"{width_px * 0.8}x{height_px * 0.8}^")
    img.extent(
        width_px,
        height_px,
        int(-(width_px - img.width) / 2),
        int(-(height_px - img.height) / 2),
    )
    img.save(filename="/tmp/out.pdf")
```

Unless I hard-code the `font` attribute as above, I get an error:

```
TypeError: font must be specified or existing in image
```

Fonts seem to be a real beast, and I neither want to hardcode a font into the
code, nor doe I want to use [TTFQuery](https://pypi.org/project/TTFQuery/) as
suggested by the docs, because that project seems unmaintained.

Instead, I'd like to just use a default font, like the command-line version
does. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: You need to set the default font in your OS or set the default font in the ImageMagick policy.xml file `<policy domain="system" name="font" value="/path/to/unicode-font.ttf"/> `

Comment: Thanks for your reply @fmw42! Unfortunately, even with the policy setting, the code still complains as I showed above, unless I explicitly hard-code a font.

Do note also that the command-line tools don't need a font, and work fine even without the policy, leading me to believe that the system does in fact have a default font.

Comment: Try using `Font('arial')` as I believe that's the default font.

Comment: Thanks @emcconville, Arial is a proprietary typeface, so I highly doubt it is the default. However, your suggestion made me try `Font('sans-serif')` and that works and will do me fine.